# How to make images blitz onto the screen in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

This is the code for the grid. I am using this in a separate file which is being called into the main file to get the units onto the screen.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

Background = pygame.display.set_mode((900 ,900))
Green = (45,198,14)
Background.fill(Green)

for i in range(0, 900, 50):
    pygame.draw.line(Background, (0, 0, 0), (0, i), (900, i))
    pygame.draw.line(Background, (0, 0, 0), (i, 0), (i, 900))
pygame.display.update()

while pygame.event.wait().type != pygame.QUIT:
    pass
```

This is the code that i have used to try get the image onto the screen:

```
import GridV5
import pygame

pygame.init()

RedInfantry= pygame.image.load("H:\computer science\6.2\Coursework\Week\Red team\InfantryRedV20.gif")



while True:
    Background.blit(RedInfantry,(0,0))
```

I have tried with other units however none will appear on the screen.

Comment: It'e a typo, `blit` rather than `blitz`. See [`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit)

Comment: Are you still struggling with this? If the top code snippet is your `GridV5` module, then your second code snippet will only display the grid until you close the window and then loop forever. Please create a [mcve] to allow the community to assist you. It may also be helpful to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

The function is 'blit' not 'blitz' so try changing that first. See docs here

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation linked? It shows you need to create a Surface and then blit onto it likeso pygame.Surface.blit()

Comment: Isn't the background the surface for the units to blit onto?